# Extracting the digits after the final underscore in a string

Tags: php

I have a string that could contain any of the following:

120_254 or 120_254_65 or 140_260_220_45 or 10_210_250_55_100

I need to be able to strip ANY of the above examples to just the digits after the last underscore.
I think i can use ltrim for this but i don't know how to code it when there are multiple instances of the underscore.

Comment: did you make an attempt to this assignment of yours?

Comment: updated my answer. it will be more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with -

```
$last = substr($str, strrpos($string, "_", -1) + 1);
var_dump($last);
```

`strrpos($string, "_", -1)` will return the last `_`'s position.

Or you can use `explode()`

```
$digits = explode('_', $data);
$last   = $digits[count($digits)-1];
```

Comment: @sgt..in strrpos function no need for -1.**strrpos( $str, '_' )** will return the same output.

Comment: yup it will...i just added it... :) if 1 want to use the offset then it will refer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explode` to get an array from the string and `array_pop` to get the last item:

```
$last = array_pop( explode( "_", $str ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `substr`:

```
$str = substr($str, strrpos( $str, '_' )+1);
```

$str will return the following output `100`